# Where can I find more information a specific parameter syntax for Javascript? (example inside)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was looking at the node.js docs and came across the documentation for method:

```
http.request(options[, callback])
```

I'm curious of why parameters (options[, callback]) is represented like this. I kind of understand how it work and the what it means. I believe it is approximately analogous to:

```
http.request = function(options=undefined, callback) { 
    // code using default values for options 
    };
```

I know it is much more than that but I'm primarily curious about the parameter representation. I can't find any information in any MDN Javascript documentations.

Is it a shorthand way of representing ECMA6 default parameters and destructuring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

square brackets are used for optional parameters, so this method needs one "options" argument and may have second "callback" argument. this is a standard way to describe method interface.

Comment: both arguments have default value of undefined. it's up to the method how it handles (in)correct input. the interface is not handled by the language, but by the code inside of the method.

Comment: @sevenbus No. It just means the second parameter is optional.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, based on the given arguments when the function was called, there are certain parameters that are optional. Generally, the syntax that you are describe it's analogue for this:

```
function someStuff(aParam, optionalParam){
   console.log("using the aParamter = " + aParam + ".The optional param it's " + (optionalParam? ("present with value = " + optionalParam ) : "notPresent" ) )
}

someStuff(1, 2);
someStuff(1);
```

IMHO, there aren't standard for this, another option for this:

```
function importantThingToDo(theMostImportantParam){
 var options = arguments[1] || {/* a default optional params*/ 
                                         option : 1
                                      };
 console.log("This callback was called with the options: " options");

}

importantThingToDo("play guitar");
importantThingToDo("play bass", {option: 2});
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the link for the NodeJS documentation, you will find the method that you are using in there [NodeJs Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html)
Options is an object where you can configure the different options/settings, for example protocol, host and hostname. This would be an example of that parameter:

```
{
   protocol: value,
   host: value,
}
```

And the parameter callback, is the function to be executed after the http.request ends, all the methods in node JS are asynchronous and non-blocking, in the first parameter you will receive an error (if there is any) and in the other parameters the response

Comment: All true, but it doesn't explain that the notation just means you don't need to provide a callback.